# What is the best way to optimize an iframe content in webpage for search engines

Tags: html, iframe, seo, search-engine

I use an iframe in my site ,

How i can let the search engines robots read and index the content , and the results point to the page including the iframe ?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell from a few Google searches, searching for text contained in an iframe brings back the iframe page only, and not the wrapper page. So the content of the iframe is not indexed with the wrapper page.

You ought to try and find a workaround for the iframes if possible. If you just need "scrollable" content you can use a div with the CSS `overflow:scroll`. Or just read the external content from the server side and include it inline with the page.

Answer (score 0):

1. optimize text in iframe-container-page and de-optimize text in iframe-content-page. use the iframe title-property and insert alternative content between opening and closing iframe-tags.
2. add javascript to iframe-content-page to check if it is loaded standalone, redirect to iframe-container-page if not:

   if(self.location==top.location) top.location.replace('http://contain.er/page-url/here');
3. optionally (but I wouldn't recommend it) you could add the iframe-content-page to robots.txt and declare it not to be indexed:

   User-agent: *
   Disallow: /iframe-content-page.html